# Software to download x seconds of a video from an HTTP server?

Tags: gratis, video, download-manager, streaming

How to download *x* seconds of a video hosted on an HTTP server?

There is an HTTP video `http://example.com/video.mp4` and I want to download *x* seconds of it. How to do it?

Requirements:

- Use less bandwidth than downloading the whole video, and then cutting it (can download a bit more if necessary and then cut).
- Result should be a valid video file, not corrupt.
- The more formats the better.
- Free.

Comment: Maybe you can use VLC's network streaming/converting feature in conjunction with its [stop time option](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=189518&sid=018f7dd0657c5a5746bfdad1d2b92d4e#p189518). (Note: this is a wild guess, I've never tried it before.)

Comment: This should work. Read this link for more information: http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html

Comment: Actually I searched for a program which can download x seconds of a **stream**, but VLC can do both (partially downloading a file or a stream, actually anything VLC can play)! It can be even done with GUI. @ComFreek convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

- You can supply a start and a stop parameter on the command line:

   See:

  - https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=189518&sid=018f7dd0657c5a5746bfdad1d2b92d4e#p189518
  - https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help
- The result can be converted or streamed to any format VLC supports.
- VLC supports the OGV format.
- VLC is free and open source.

Comment: Is there a way to provide time in h:m:s without converting it to seconds?

Comment: @SmitJohnt There is no way to do that, as far as I know. You can write a shell/Batch/PowerShell script to automate the conversion.

Comment: I want to use it from GUI